# How to Execute every package.json in the node.js project

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have multi module project structure in node.js. Main project has one package.json and inner modules have there own package.json. I have to execute the main package.json with inner ones. How should i tell main package.json to execute others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "execute the main package.json"? `package.json` is a JSON file. It cannot be "executed".

Answer (score 0):

By using local paths: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

```
{
  "name": "Main module",
  "dependencies": {
    "sub-module-1": "file:./my/local/path"
  }
}
```

Specify all of your submodules in the dependencies section of your main `package.json` and then run your regular npm commands (`npm install`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by writing a shell script.